# How can I remove duplicates from DataSource with groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui, datasource

I have a data source file in SOAP UI which have multiple duplicate values and I want to send the file after removing duplicates. Do you have any idea how to do this

Comment: Check your database query, can you not eliminate the duplicates there ? What does the data look like ?

Comment: My data source is an excel file. I get that from the jenkins workspace. I have a list of flight numbers in a column on the excel file like this :                                            FLIGHT NUMBER
1
1
12
12
13
13
1
14
15
16
17
2644

Comment: How are you reading the excel file?

Comment: I am reading the file by DataSink

Comment: Could you provide the actual code which we should check out?

Comment: @ninj I only use the open source version of SoapUI so I have not worked with DataSinks before. I do all my data handling in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to prevent creating duplicate values before data-sinking them. I couldn't find a solution to removing duplicates from a data sink file.